# Where can I find more information on the internal architecture of the Intel 4004?

Tags: intel-4004

I've been studying this chip lately. I can easily find block-level architecture or transistor-level diagrams on the web, but nothing in between.

For example, I'm curious about how the 2-word instructions are implemented, or how the ALU is implemented specifically.

Does anyone know is this knid of information is available anywhere?

Comment: You may want to mention the resources you're already familiar with, so that people will not have to waste their time responding with information which would not be helpful to you.

Comment: A description of the 4004 using Verilog can be found at https://opencores.org/projects/mcs-4

Comment: This [transistor-level schematic](http://datasheets.chipdb.org/Intel/MCS-4/4004_schematic.pdf) is pretty well annotated.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want. Conceptual? Logical? Physical? Signals/timing? Flowchart? How those interact with each other?

Comment: I'm looking for something more at the logical level.

Answer (score 21):

The following references contain more detailed information than can be found in the Intel 4004 datasheets.

- The [MCS-4 Assembly Language Programming Manual](http://www.nj7p.org/Manuals/PDFs/Intel/MCS-4_ALPM_Dec73.pdf) (Intel, 1973) has information about the stack, memory addressing, and arithmetic operations.
- The [MCS-4 Micro Computer Set Users Manual](https://www.hartetechnologies.com/manuals/Intel/MCS-4_UsersManual_Feb73.pdf) (Intel, 1973) has information about the instructions and how the 4004 communicates with the external world.
- The [MCS-40 User's Manual for Logic Designers](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/components/intel/MCS40/MCS-40_Users_Manual_Nov74.pdf) (Intel, 1974) has a more detailed block diagram (Figure 1-4) and a slightly more detailed discussion of the instructions (e.g., JCN on page 1-30).

Answer (score 21):

Two IEEE papers written by Federico Faggin, the chief designer of the 4004:

- [*The History of the 4004*](https://archive.org/10/items/HistoryOfThe4004/history_of_4004.pdf), written by Faggin and three other members of the 4004 design team, for *IEEE Micro*, Dec. 1996.  Includes timing diagrams and block diagrams of the 4004 CPU.
- [*The Making of the First Microprocessor*](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=4776530), solely by Faggin, for *IEEE Solid-State Circuits Magazine*, Winter 2009.  More oriented at the transistor and gate levels of the design.  Also describes the 4001, 4002, and 4003 chips.